# Convert Rankine temperatures to Celsius

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review, iterator

I have this [Python Package](https://github.com/eddyyxxyy/ToTemp) called [`ToTemp`](https://pypi.org/project/totemp/) under development for precise Temperature Conversions and currently thinking in changing the method's implementation to be able to convert multiple values and return an `Iterable` with those converted values (in a list).

It would be good to see some reviews on this.

Default implementation:

```py
    class Rankine:
    """Provides conversion of Rankine to other temperature scales"""

        @staticmethod
        def to_celsius(rankine: float | int, /, *, float_ret=True) -> float | int:
        """
        Converts Rankine to Celsius, returning a float by default.

        If the float_ret parameter is False, it returns an approximate int value
        (using the math's module trunc function).

        :param rankine: Rankine value(s) to be converted
        :param float_ret: Optional, True by default to return floats
        :return: float, int or Iterable
        """
        if float_ret:
            return float((rankine - 491.67) * 5/9)
        return trunc((rankine - 491.67) * 5/9)
```

Now, with the `iter()` method:

```py
    class Rankine:
    """Provides conversion of Rankine to other temperature scales"""

        @staticmethod
        def to_celsius(rankine: float | int | Iterable, /, *, float_ret=True) -> float | int | Iterable:
            """
            Converts Rankine to Celsius, returning a float by default.

            If the float_ret parameter is False, it returns an approximate int value
            (using the math's module trunc function).

            :param rankine: Rankine value(s) to be converted
            :param float_ret: Optional, True by default to return floats
            :return: float, int or Iterable
            """
            try:
                iter(rankine)
                if float_ret:
                    return [float((value - 491.67) * 5/9) for value in rankine]
                return [trunc((value - 491.67) * 5/9) for value in rankine]
            except TypeError:
                if float_ret:
                    return float((rankine - 491.67) * 5/9)
                return trunc((rankine - 491.67) * 5/9)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Unit Typing

You are under-using the `Rankine` class, and I presume the other temperature classes.

**Primitive Obsession** (only manipulating primitive types) means never being quite sure which unit a type is in. When you have a temperature value in hand, is it expressed in Kelvin? Rankine? Celsius? Anything else? In fact... is it even a temperature?

Instead, make `Rankine` a `@dataclass`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, NewType, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound=int | float)

@dataclass
class Rankine(Generic[T]):
    value: T
```

Then, you can write conversion methods in a generic manner.

#### User's Pick

Let the user pick the type they wish automatically, and do not change it "under their back" with an option:

```
    def to_rankine(self) -> 'Rankine[T]':
        return Rankine(self.value)

    def to_celsius(self) -> 'Celsius[T]':
        celsius = type(self.value)((self.value - 491.67) * 5/9)

        return Celsius(celsius)
```

Instead, provide explicit methods to change the underlying type:

```
    def with_float(self) -> 'Rankine[float]':
        return Rankine(float(self.value))

    def with_int(self) -> 'Rankine[int]':
        return Rankine(int(self.value))
```

This means that any underlying type change is explicit, rather than the result of accidentally using the default option.

Comment: Can't I let the user put a list/tuple? Like: Rankine([12, 44.5, 25])?

Comment: I would advise against it. From a modelling point of view, what you'd want out is a `List[Rankine[float]]` (or `List[Rankine[int]]`), you could use a dedicated function to do so, but `map(Rankine, [12.0, 44.5, 25.0])` should also do the job.

Comment: Something like:
rankine_temps = [12, 24.55, 95, 999]
map(Rankine.to_celsius, rankine_temps)
?

Comment: You'd need something like `temps = map(Rankine, [12, 24.55, 95, 999]); map(Rankine.to_celsius, temps)`. First identify the correct unit of each numeric value (Rankine here), then convert it into another unit (Celsius here). You could also just use a more complex function to avoid materalizing a list of rankine temps just to throw it away.

Comment: "avoid materalizing a list of rankine temps just to throw it away", didn't understood this, can you explain it more?

Answer (score 12):

## Let the caller handle iterables

I think allowing an iterable is a bad idea. The caller can already use `map(Rankine.to_celsius, temps)` or the like with your first version. And it should be up to the caller to process an iterable.

Image a caller passing in a huge generator and you construct a large list that might result in an OOM error condition. Don't force the caller to use a list as iterable. Also your type hint is misleading, since it will not return an Iterable, but explicitly a `list`.

## Handle return type dependent on the input type

As for the `float_ret`: I don't like that either. If you want to return either a float or an int, I'd change the API to return the type that's been passed in:

```py
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T', bound=int | float)


class Rankine:
    """Provides conversion of Rankine to other temperature scales"""

    @staticmethod
    def to_celsius(rankine: T) -> T:
        ...

        return type(rankine)((rankine - 491.67) * 5/9)

...

print(Rankine.to_celsius(12))
print(Rankine.to_celsius(12.0))
```

Make sure to document this behaviour in the docstring.

## [Stop writing classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)

And as `Rankine` only contains one classmethod, you can just refactor it to a pure function:

```py
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T', bound=int | float)


def rankine_to_celsius(rankine: T) -> T:
    ...

    return type(rankine)((rankine - 491.67) * 5/9)

...

print(rankine_to_celsius(12))
print(rankine_to_celsius(12.0))
```

Comment: Ty for all those very nice observations Richard! I only showed one method, but there's other 6 conversions in each <temp_scale> class.

Comment: Why are there 6 conversion functions in each class?  You just need a slope and offset to convert any value to/from kelvins, and therefore to any other temperature scale.

Comment: @eddyxide I can only review the code, you present here.

Comment: @TobySpeight could you show me an example?

Comment: Yes - [one in C++](/a/279529/75307).

Comment: And [one in Python](/a/159264/75307).